# Build borders in unity tbs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game in unity something like Total war just for fun (a turn based strategy game) and I have problems in building the border of civilizations i don't know what to use.I was looking at Grids in unity but is not want i want it to do.Please if you can give me some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some kind of outliner shader to the group of gameobjects that belong to the civilization, there are some on the Unity store or on Google for example this http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse